# change an element from display none to display block simple html dom

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

so here is what I have and it works perfectly:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://localhost/index.html');
```

in this page resides a button called "phone number", once you click on it it opens a div

```
<div class="phone" style="display: none;">
<span class="number"> 212-222-3453</span>
</div>
```

is there a away to change it to display:block before I scrape the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the below code.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('index.html');
$phoneArray = $html->find('div[class=phone]'); 
$phoneArray[0]->style="display:block";
```